# Are intercepted https requests impossible to redirect?

Tags: redirect, https

I'm building a Linux firewall box to only allow access to white-listed sites.  I haven't done this sort of work for 10 years.

In the old days, it was trivial to intercept and redirect a request for http://www.example.com to http://firewall/notallowed.

On the modern web, there exist many links to https URLs.

Assuming SNI, am I right in thinking that such a request could only be redirected if you had a valid certificate for the originally requested site.  (Which, of course, an intercepting firewall wouldn't have.)

Do modern captive portals solve this https issue in some way - or does the user's browser just display an error, rather than a helpful reason for the page being blocked?

Comment: Cross-stack see http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/2914/can-my-company-see-what-https-sites-i-went-to -- http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/7323/is-my-company-tracking-me  -- http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/8145/does-https-prevent-man-in-the-middle-attacks-by-proxy-server -- http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/48170/how-a-provider-can-tap-an-internet-line-even-for-ssl-encrypted-connection -- http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/106910/corporate-computers-have-own-corporations-cert-as-trusted-ca-should-i-consider and more

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're trying to proxy an HTTPS request and you can't provide a valid certificate the only things you can do is to either pass it through untouched or  to cause an error. Anything else would completely undermine the purpose of HTTPS.

Enterprises that, for whatever reason, decide to inspect and/or block TLS traffic from their client machines typically achieve this by installing their own root certificate on their client machines. This in turn makes it possible for them to insert a proxy server which can generate valid certificates as needed (valid from the perspective of their clients).
The flip-side is of course that having your own certificate installed on client machines is also a big liability, in addition to the privacy concerns of inspecting TLS traffic in the first place.

That approach is obviously only possible if you are in control of all the client machines.

If this is about guest machines or some other scenario where the above is unacceptable, this is not really something that you can do in a "nice" way.